# Gmail's label and skip the inbox filter

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I am using Gmail. I want incoming mail that matches a label to skip the inbox.  This does not seem to work.  The instructions from Gmail include the following:

> To keep organized, many people like to have incoming messages
>   automatically labeled and removed from their inbox until they can look
>   at them later at a more convenient time. If you want to do this, make
>   sure to select Skip the Inbox (Archive it) and Apply the label: when
>   you create your filter.

The filter looks like this:

> Matches: from:(jean123@yahoo.com) Do this: Skip Inbox, Apply
>   label "Jean123", Never send it to Spam

However, such mail continues to appear in the inbox as well as `All Mail`.  What am I doing wrong?  (It also appears in a label for "Jean123" and I'm not sure how it got there but that is beside the point.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This can be fixed by using the `Inbox` settings page and uncheck the option to have `important` mail ignore filters.

Comment: Also, ALL Mail goes to the "All Mail" box regardless of filters as the name implies..

Answer (score 3):

The Inbox setting `Filtered mail:Override filters - Include important messages in the inbox that may have been filtered out.` will keep the hidden label "Inbox".

All messages have the "All Mail" label. The Override tells gmail not to strip the "Inbox" label if it believes the message is important. Your filer added the "Jean123"  label, and kept it out of spam.

Answer (score 1):

goto:
settings → Filters and Blocked Addresses → edit (particular label) → Continue → Skip the Inbox (checked)

Comment: I don't know why people put down vote. I have answered to asked question. If you put down vote please put a comment for reason

Comment: The OP said he already enabled "skip the inbox".

Comment: That is the most useful answer.

Comment: @RicardoCruz, `I am using Gmail. I want incoming mail that matches a label to skip the inbox. This does not seem to work.` the steps in the answer resolve exactly the problem an author has.

Comment: @RicardoCruz, `The OP said he already enabled "skip the inbox".` no, the OP did not say that

Comment: @manymanymore The OP says "The filter looks like this: (...) Skip Inbox" It was already enabled.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about existing emails appearing in inbox, maybe you skipped this step:

**"Also apply to matching conversations"**

before updating the filter.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting the label added then that confirms that the filter is being applied, and then if most messages skip the inbox but only a few make it to the inbox then it is likely that Gmail is overriding your filter.

There is hidden setting under Settings > Inbox > Filter mail with two settings:
* Override filters - Include important messages in the inbox that may have been filtered out. (default)
* Don't override filters

Choose "Don't override filters".

[image: Screenshot of Gmail's "Filtered Mail" setting.]

source: https://www.theinternetpatrol.com/gmail-skip-the-inbox-filter-not-working-this-may-be-why-and-how-to-fix-it/