# Gmail Filter Not Archiving Emails

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

I have the following Gmail filter:

```
Matches: to:(marketing.emails@mail.com)
Do this: Skip Inbox, Mark as read, Apply label "marketing.emails@mail.com", Never mark it as important
```

**The filter marks the messages as read, but it doesn't archive the emails.  They remain in my inbox.**

If I open the filter, it finds the emails in my inbox.  If I check "*Also apply the filter to matching conversations*", the matching emails in my inbox are successfully archived.  But future emails don't get archived.  This is the issue - I don't want to manually apply the filter everyday.

---

A similar question is asked [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33758/gmails-label-and-skip-the-inbox-filter).  The answers are to go to Settings→Inbox→Filtered Mail and unchecking the option: "*Override filters - Include important messages in the inbox that may have been filtered out.*"

I have already unchecked this option and the issue remains, so please don't suggest this solution.

---

Note - This filter is applied to emails that are received through Gmailify.  Since the "*Mark as read*" portion of the filter works, I don't know if this is a relevant detail.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the filter rules themselves are correct, on the next screen these options are critical, specifically:

> Skip the Inbox (Archive it)

> Never send it to Spam

> Never mark it as important

Users may also be interested in the other two checked boxes:

[image]