# How do I get labeled emails to skip my inbox?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels

I'm currently working in a role where I get many emails from many different teams, and these emails will usually end up being ~30-50 email long threads. Some of them are relevant to me, and some are not, but that can't be determined based on keywords. I have to follow the first few emails of each thread before I can determine if I am needed or not.

I understand I can use filters to skip the inbox or apply labels, but that's not what I want to do. I want all emails to come through my inbox at first, and then I'd like to manually label an email as "skip". Once the skip label has been applied, then I'd like Gmail to keep those out of my main inbox. Does anyone know of a way to do this? I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/33758/88163